# How can I get pieces from a cell fractured mesh to fall into an "open" cube or bowl?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am trying to get the pieces from a cell fractured object to fall into another object like an open cube, but they always hit the "missing" face and spread out rather than going down into the cube. How can I modify the cube to allow this, other than simply deleting the face?  Imagine dropping a handful of pebbles into an open box; that's the basic idea. I can't seem to get them past the "invisible" top face - the face I thought I deleted.

Comment: Make sure that the cube shape is set to Mesh and not Convex Hull, if it's not your problem, please share your file